# Create a bitmap in memory and use it

Tags: c, winapi, bitmap

My goal is to create a bitmap in memory and use its handle as a parameter of the BM_SETIMAGE message (a message that set a button's bitmap).

The following is my code:

```
........

        HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
        HDC memDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
        HBITMAP hMemBmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, 100, 100);
        HBITMAP hOldBmp = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(memDC, hMemBmp);
        Rectangle(memDC, 0, 0, 100, 100);

        HBRUSH brush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0xff, 0xff, 0x00));

        RECT rc;
        rc.left   = 0; 
        rc.top    = 0;
        rc.right  = 100;
        rc.bottom = 100;
        FillRect(memDC, &rc, brush);

        SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_SET_START_PAGE_BG), BM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)hMemBmp);

........
```

but it doesn't work, I just got black color on my button.

Questions:

1. Does `FillRect(memDC, &rc, brush)` modify the content of hMemBmp? If not, what `SelectObject(memDC, hMemBmp)` did for these 2 objects?
2. Should I use `CreateBitmap` instead of `CreateCompatibleBitmap` to do my task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should select the old bitmap back into the memory DC before you send the message. [According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162957%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) a bitmap can be selected into only a single DC at a time.

Comment: Thanks, it works. So after SelectObject(memDC, hOldBmp), the hMemBmp is selected into hdc and hOldBmp is selected into memDC, is this right?

Comment: @user565739: No, nobody is selecting anything into `hdc`.  After that line `hMemBmp` will be separate from any DC and have the image inside -- that's exactly what `BM_SETIMAGE` is expecting, an unattached bitmap containing your image.